# Formatting cells in XSLX files generated by XSLT

Tags: excel, xslt, xlsx, date-formatting, cell-formatting

I'm using XSLT to generate a report with a date column. In the spreadsheet XLSX file, if I pass through the date as a string, when opening it with a spreadsheet package such as Excel, it will assume it's a date (which is correct) but then format it as `MM/dd/yyyy` when what we actually want is `dd/MM/yyyy`. This appears to be the spreadsheet package that is causing this, however I was wondering if you could define cell formatting from the XSLT?

Here is the code I'm using to do this:

```
<xsl:template match="SomeTemplate">
  <Row>
    ...
    <Cell>
      <xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(StartTime, 'dd/MM/yyyy')" />
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ms:format-time(StartTime, 'HH:mm:ss')" />
    </Cell>
    ...
  </Row>
</xsl:template>
```

I've attempted other ways around this such as starting the cell with `'` but strangely this didn't work!

Here's an XML sample relevant to the XSLT above:

```
...
<Destination>
  <StartTime>2013-03-07T00:01:09</StartTime>
  <EndTime>2013-03-07T10:41:09</EndTime>
  ...
</Destination>
...
```

Comment: Could you post a small sample of the actual XML being generated (just a sample with one or two rows will do)? Thanks!

Comment: Is that the XML before or also you do the transformation?

Comment: XML as passed into the XSLT. The output is XLSX for Excel.

Comment: XLSX is actually a binary file (it's a zip file). Do you mean Excel XML as your output? It may help if you post a snippet of the output. If it is Excel XML, I think I may be able to help....

Answer (score 0):

The cell formatting in Excel xml can be done via styles.

I.e you fill the cells with dates in xs:datetime format (you do not need any ms:format-date conversion at all in your example) but specify the cell style though ss:styleId:

```
<Destination>
  <StartTime>2013-03-07T00:01:09</StartTime>
  <EndTime>2013-03-07T10:41:09</EndTime>
</Destination>
```

+

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Workbook>
        <Styles>
            <Style ss:ID="style_default">
                <NumberFormat ss:Format="Short Date"/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="style_ddslashmmslashyy">
                <NumberFormat ss:Format="dd/mm/yy;@"/>
            </Style>
        </Styles>
        <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
            <Table>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </Table>
        </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Destination">
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="style_default">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime"><xsl:value-of select="StartTime"/></Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="style_ddslashmmslashyy">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime"><xsl:value-of select="StartTime"/></Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```